# acceleration output interpretation

Tags: accelerometer

I'm using [LSM9DS1](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/1e/3f/2a/d6/25/eb/48/46/DM00103319.pdf/files/DM00103319.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00103319.pdf) accelerometer which I configured with 16g range.

I left the device without movement and I got following accelerations

x : 0

y : 0

z : 1300

the device is subjected only to gravity, hence the positive value got in Z

my question is what's the origin of the value 1300, the earth gravity acceleration is 9.81 m/s²

Comment: normally it is calibrated for 1g =0  not freefall (0g)

Comment: sorry I don't get you, if 1g = 0, so do you mean that 1300 = 1300 g??

Comment: The resolution is probably **mili g**, though the datasheet should tell.

Comment: What if you flip it?

Comment: if I flip it vertically, I got (x :0, y 1300, z :0)

Comment: @BenceKaulics yes the resolution is mili g

Comment: 1300 *exactly*? I would guess your reading method is wrong

Comment: @EugeneSh. no not exactly, 1344, 1337 ....

Comment: What if you flip it upside down, so the value becomes negative?

Comment: @EugeneSh. YES i FLIPPED DOWN AND the values become negative

Comment: *What* are the values?

Comment: @EugeneSh. -133? -1347 -1327 ...

Comment: @brhans I dont think so, I the values are given on a signed 16 bytes, I already get correct values from x and y, (-2 -1 -0 1 2 3 ...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it would help to read the part of the datasheet where it tells you the output units?

From page 12 of the datasheet:
Linear acceleration sensitivity FS = ±16g  0.732mg/LSB

So take the reading, multiply by 0.732 and then divide by 1,000 to get the acceleration in g.

1340 * 0.732 / 1000 = 0.981g

edit - Note that is 0.981g NOT 9.81m/s, it's 20mg off, well within the margin of error of the sensor, that the value happens to be the same digits as 1g measured in m/s is just a confusing coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

You choose +/-16g range for full scale then follow calibration methods to get 0 output at rest, if that is what you want, otherwise compute mg sensitivity.

- also facing true north for mag.